# Trigger the button.click event From another page

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, popup

I am trying to trigger the button.click event of the page 1 from Popup page.
There is Grid-View in Page 1 with the edit button for each row. when the button is clicked the popup page is opened.
User can Save or cancel the edit page.
Cancel will close the popup page "Using JavaScript".
Save will update the database and then close the popup page.
When the popup page is closed the Grid-View in page 1 should be update with the new data. which i am doing by

```
protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    GridView1.DataBind();
}
```

But my problem is how can i call this button.click event from the popup page ?? 
Or Is there anyway that i can update the Grid-View in page 1 with out reloading the page ??
Sorry for English "mistake"
Thank you

Comment: http://www.obout.com/grid/grid_refresh_records.aspx

Answer (score 0):

In your popup you can use the javascript window.opener() to get an instance of the original window where your GridView is.

```
window.opener().document.getElementById('btnSave').click();
```